# Cross-domain JavaScript code with sibling sub-domains

Tags: javascript, cross-domain, subdomain, siblings

I have two web applications setups:

**david**.example.com and **john**.example.com

David opens a new window to John:

```
window.open('john.example.com');
```

John would now like to set an input element back on David:

```
$("#input", window.opener.document).val("Hello David.");
```

My problem is that this doesn't work on most modern browser because of cross-domain scripting security. I've also tried setting `document.domain` to different domain combinations both on David and John with no success.

The only time this does work is if John is on `example.com` and both have `document.domain` set to `example.com`. However, `example.com` is our main website and is not available as a solution.

So is there a way I can do the above example while making the solution works in all modern security conscious browsers?

Notes

- *I control `example.com` and all its sub domains.*
- *David and John are separate web applications and cannot be hosted on the same sub-domain.*

Comment: What do you mean with "However, example.com is our main website and is not available as a solution."? Setting `document.domain` to `"example.com"` is the right solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should be able to do this, as long as you set document.domain on both DOM's.

```
document.domain = location.host.replace(/^.*?([^.]+\.[^.]+)$/g,'$1');
```

Credited to Martin Jespersen

Answer (score -1):

You can always use iframes for cross domain communication and send messages via the hashbangs. See [this](http://softwareas.com/cross-domain-communication-with-iframes) for an example. It's basically the workings of stuff like Facebook connect. If one app opens the other window I'm guessing you can do that with normal windows as well.

Comment: This doesn't work anymore in modern browsers like Chrome and FF4 :(

Comment: It doesn't? I guess you could use the HTML5 features for it if available in a newer browser (see http://html5demos.com/postmessage2).