# How to submit data from new page to older page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I got a Button on HTML form (let's call it Form_A) which when clicked, opens a new window (let's call it Form_B).

When user fill in some information in Form_B form and hit submit (or just a button), I need to send some processed information back to 'Form_A' and close 'Form_B.'

How can I accomplish it?

Comment: by calling a function on `window.opener` and pass the data as an argument

Comment: Why do you need to open a new window? You can have a `div` with `display:none` css and on clicking the button, you can make it visible (api.jquery.com/show). Then on clicking another button related to the div or submitting the form( keep the div in  form B ) you can get the info from here to form B. use  api.jquery.com/submit to submit form without opening another window.

Comment: @IstiaqueAhmed I can't explain the whole business requirement over here and I guess, neither would you be interested... Let's just say, I need it, and I found the solution as well... Check my comments below

Comment: @adeneo thanks, you answer directed me to right direction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is best illustrated with an example.  In the code of Form_A:

```
<div id="target"></div> <button onclick="window.open('form_b.html'); return false">Open Form B</button>

function receive_data (value)
{
    $("#target").text(value);
}
```

In the code of Form_B:

```
<input type="button" onclick="window.opener.receive_data('hello'); window.close();">
```

Comment: Works fine on IE, but gives security exception on Chrome. Do you think, it can be because I am running it locally. Finally, these two files will be hosted across different sub-domain of a website.

Comment: Dunn know why it was giving error locally, when I deployed it (after fixing the sub-domain issue), it was working fine for all browsers. Appending code in my Question. Thanks for snippet.

Comment: Chrome applies stricter security standards to javascript running from local files than ones downloaded from a web server.  It's perverse, but true.

Comment: SOLUTION:
===========
a.html
=======

<div id="target"></div> <button onclick="document.domain = 'topdomain.com';window.open('http://xyz.topdomain.com/b.html'); return false">Open Form B</button>
<script>
function receive_data (value)
{
alert(value); /* Dunn bother what I am doing here... */
}
</script>

b.html
=======
<form>
<input type="button" onclick="document.domain = 'topdomain.com'; window.opener.receive_data('hello');window.close();" value='click to close'>
</form>

This helped - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5183684/cross-domain-javascript-code-with-sibling-sub-domains

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `localStorage`, like:

```
<!--FormB-->
<input type="submit" onclick="processInfo();" />
```

and in your javascript code:

```
function processInfo(){
    //process your information then
    //let's day you have 2 variables as a result of your process
    var info1 = "My Information 1";
    var info2 = "My Information 2";
    localStorage.setItem("info1", info1);
    localStorage.setItem("info2", info2);
}
```

then in your code on the next page get your variables whenever you wanted like:

```
    function getInfo1(){
        return localStorage.getItem("info1");
    }

    function getInfo2(){
        return localStorage.getItem("info2");
    }
```

and the other solution for ancient browsers is using `window.opener`, you can use it in your close function like this:

```
<!--FormB-->
<input type="button" onclick="closeWindow();" />
```

javascript code:

```
function closeWindow(){
    //process your information then
    //let's day you have 2 variables as a result of your process
    var info1 = "My Information 1";
    var info2 = "My Information 2";

    window.opener._info1 = info1;
    window.opener._info2 = info2;

    window.close();
}
```

then you can get them in the main page like:

```
    function getInfo1(){
        return window._info1;
    }

    function getInfo2(){
        return window._info2;
    }
```

BTW, we usually use `_` when we want to simulate private variable, whereas they are not really private.

Comment: Thanks, but I can't use local storage in my scenario... ancient browsers

Comment: @user3133397: I changed my answer, now check it out.

Comment: thanks for your efforts but i had already started working on it when your answer arrived. Now, I got a fix which is addressing my whole problem. Thanks anyways.